# File upload w/ expressjs v4.+

Tags: file-upload, express

I am trying to move to express 4.+ and I am having trouble figuring out what I should do about file uploads.

Migration docs says I need to come up w/ an alternative but they don't really give an example.  They also dropped support for a reason, which file upload package should I use?

Also read that you should not attach a form upload to every post by using:

```
app.use(multer(...));
```

Is there a good way to attach these to just a particular route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) or [busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy) are options.

Expressjs 4.+ has lost this feature because it's not built on top of connect anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I use *connect-busboy*. I could not get 'busboy' to work. Other packages I came across but have never played with are 'flow' and 'parted'. There is also a npm package 'mongoose-file' which seems to let you add a file upload path to a mongoose Schema for upload to server. It may be handy if you are uploading other data to a MongoDB?

Basic *connect-busboy* and *Formidable* example using Express V4.2: 
[Node/Express file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691194/node-express-file-upload)