# Handling form data in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-connect, node.js-domains

I am uploading a csv file from my client side javascript as Post request to my node server. I am able to handle the request on the nodejs server as well. Please help me in fetching the file and parsing the file on the server side. The file will be a csv file and I need to parse the file and read the contents of the file.

I am attaching the source code snippet for uploading the file on the client side as well as the server side below for reference.

```
myAngularApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
  this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
        .success(function(){
           // handling on success data
        })
        .error(function(){
           // handling on error data
        });
  }
```

On NodeJs server:

```
router.post('/filter-reports', function(req, res) {
  console.log('Came inside the Node js router.. Now.. its all up to me to format the data....');
  console.log(req);
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node/Express file upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691194/node-express-file-upload)

Comment: You've given little info.So could you do a console.log on req.body and req.files and see where the file is present.I ask this because with express.4.0+ we cannot use bodyparser to handle multi-form data.

Answer (score -2):

I think you are not using multer for handling the multipart/formdata requests.

Mention

```
var multer  =   require('multer');
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './public');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
  }
});
```

in the above code.

`/public` is the directory in which your file will be saved; you can change it and filename will be changed to original filename with timestamp. They are optional fields here.

Then, in `req.file` or `req.files` you will get your file info or to access the file `req.files.path` will be used, or give a try to busboy if don't want to save file and want to do operation in buffer.