# Get full file path in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an application which uploads csv file into a particular folder, say, "uploads".
Now I want to get the full path of that csv file, for example, `D:\MyNodeApp\uploads\Test.csv`.

How do I get the file location in Node.js? I used multer to upload file.

Comment: Need to know what info you have to start with.  Do you already have the filename without the path?  Do all files go into the same folder?  Is this folder a known location at run time?  A code example may help here.

Answer (score 208):

```
var path = require("path");
var absolutePath = path.resolve("Relative file path");
```

You dir structure for example:

C:->WebServer->Public->Uploads->MyFile.csv

and your working directory would be Public for example, path.resolve would be like that.

```
path.resolve("./Uploads/MyFile.csv");
```

POSIX home/WebServer/Public/Uploads/MyFile.csv
WINDOWS C:\WebServer\Public\Uploads\MyFile.csv

this solution is multiplatform and allows your application to work on both windows and posix machines.

Comment: I feel like this should be the accepted answer, as it is a lot more helpful and practical than the other answers.

Comment: You saved my day, after trying out many different solutions to accomplish this simple task (getting absolute path) your answer worked finally

Answer (score 14):

### Get all files from folder and print each file description.

```
const path = require( "path" );
const fs = require( 'fs' );
const log = console.log;
const folder = './';

fs.readdirSync( folder ).forEach( file => {
   
   const extname = path.extname( file );
   const filename = path.basename( file, extname );
   const absolutePath = path.resolve( folder, file );

   log( "File : ", file );
   log( "filename : ", filename );
   log( "extname : ", extname );
   log( "absolutePath : ", absolutePath);

});
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are using multer with express, try this in your controller method:

```
var path = require('path');

//gets your app's root path
var root = path.dirname(require.main.filename)

// joins uploaded file path with root. replace filename with your input field name
var absolutePath = path.join(root,req.files['filename'].path)
```

Answer (score 5):

In TypeScript, I did the following based on the relative file path.

```
import { resolve } from 'path';

public getValidFileToUpload(): string {
  return resolve('src/assets/validFilePath/testFile.csv');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a "dirent" type:

```
const path = require( "path" );
full_path = path.resolve( path_to_folder_containing__dir_ent__ , dir_ent.name );
```

Class: fs.Dirent
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_dirent_name

Module: fs.path
https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest option is:
dirname module: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname

filename: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_filename

console.log(__dirname)

console.log(__filename)