# Creating and submitting a form using node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node.js. I need to create and submit a form with a file to a url.

What is the way to do it?

I'm not able to find clear information about it.

I don't want to use [form-data](https://github.com/form-data/form-data) to do this simple thing moreover it requires a series of dependent modules.

I've used [nodejs-websocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodejs-websocket) module to create a server which listens from browser clients.

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691194/node-express-file-upload

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: @mzedeler I don't know Express and I'm already using nodejs-websocket module for creating server. I'll learn Express but is there any solution without using it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [express/multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) for handling file upload in the server side. Its much simple.


Use an AJAX request on the client side to upload the file when the button is clicked.

```
<form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
   .....
   <input type="file"/>
<form />


$('#upload_button_id').click(function (event) { 
  $('#form_id').on('submit', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 

    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]); 

    $.ajax({
      type:'post,'
      url: '/url/fileupload/', //the URL to your node.js server that has data
      dataType: 'json',
      data: formData, 
      cache: false, 
      contentType: false, 
      processData: false, 
      success: function(response){
         //file was uploaded successfuly 
         alert(response);
      },
      error: function(){
         //Something went wrong
      } 
   });
  });
});
```