# Read a file embedded in a HTML form in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Scenario: I have a simple HTML page as below

```
<form action="http://example.com/nodejs/endpoint" 
  method="post" 
  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>
    Select JSON file
    <input type="file" name="json">
</label>
<input type="submit">
```

Requirement: Please help me parse the json file selected by the user in my Nodejs application. I have tried all google result. 
Also i am behind a proxy.So is that a reason for not getting the file ?

The code i tried looks like

```
    console.log("In json parsing");
var fs=require('fs');
var path=require('path');
fs.readFile(req.files.json.path,function(err,data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691194/node-express-file-upload

Comment: @Gothdo..So i need to download the file to some location and read from that instead of parsing the file on the fly?