# unable to return variable in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm returning the variable uploadFile from my function and when I'm trying to access it in another variable it gives me undefined

```
function upload(req, res, callback) {
    var dir = 'uploads/';

    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(dir);
    }

    console.log(req.files.file1);
    console.log(req.files.file2);

    var uploadFiles = {
        ext1: path.extname(req.files.file1.originalname),
        path1: req.files.file1.path,
        ext2: path.extname(req.files.file2.originalname),
        path2: req.files.file2.path
    }
    return callback(uploadFiles);
}
```

this is the function where I'm calling the `upload function` I guess I'm doing it the wrong way, I'm getting `Callback is not a function` as the error ... please guide me

```
function sendMail(req, res) {
    var data = req.body;
     upload(req,res);
// checking the condition if the file has been uploaded
    if (uploadFiles) {
        data_to_send.attachments = [{
            filename: 'file1' + uploadFiles.file1ext,
            filePath: uploadFiles.file1Path 
        }, {
            filename: 'file2' + uploadFiles.file2ext,
            filePath: uploadFiles.file2Path
        }]
    }
    console.log(data_to_send.attachments)
    smtpTransport.sendMail({
            from: data_to_send.from,
            to: data_to_send.to,
            subject: data_to_send.subject,
            atachments: data_to_send.attachments,
            text: data_to_send.text,
            html: data_to_send.html
        },
//.........
```

Comment: this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691194/node-express-file-upload) help you

Comment: Maybe your hitting an exception, try wrapping the whole function in a try/catch and see if anything gets caught.

Comment: looks like you should not get undefined. how to you get back the value and use it?

Comment: even though I'm doing console(uploadFiles) in another function, I'm getting undefined

Comment: can you show us how you are calling upload?

Comment: what about trying to call a callback? Say `function upload(req, res, cb) { //logic .. }` then call `cb(uploadFiles)` at the end of the function?

Comment: How can I use that callback in another function to check  a condition if uploadFiles exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your upload function you are not checking that *callback* was actually passed (and not undefined). Also, you are not returning your values, you are actually returning whatever callback is returning.

Here is some code that might help you:

```
// inside your upload function
var uploadFiles = {
        ext1: path.extname(req.files.file1.originalname),
        path1: req.files.file1.path,
        ext2: path.extname(req.files.file2.originalname),
        path2: req.files.file2.path
    }
if (callback) {
    callback(uploadFiles);
}

//inside your sendMail (notice the 3rd parameter passed to upload)
upload(req, res, function (uploadFiles) {
    if (uploadFiles) {
        data_to_send.attachments = [{
            filename: 'file1' + uploadFiles.file1ext,
            filePath: uploadFiles.file1Path 
        }, {
            filename: 'file2' + uploadFiles.file2ext,
            filePath: uploadFiles.file2Path
        }]
    }
    // rest of the code goes here, inside the callback.
});
```

Now you will actually receive your files in the callback, as you wanted.

Comment: thanks that was helpful , I really need to learn more about coding and javascript . Can u please invite me for a chat so that I can learn more from you

Answer (score -2):

This is a scoping issue. You can't call uploadFiles in another function because you are defining it in upload. You can try defining it outside of upload, or you can try console(upload(params you are passing in)). Option three, I am completely mistaken by what you are asking.

Here is a good reference to scoping in Javascript:
[What is the scope of variables in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: Misconception, he is not accessing the variable he is accessing the returned data (in that case uploadFiles variable) ..