# Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'

Tags: javascript, file-upload, form-data

I have an uploader that allows a user to upload several pictures. In order to only create or update the images he wants to add/change, I update an object that looks like this:

`{main: Blob, "1": Blob, "2":Blob}`

So if only needs to update "1" later, the sent object will only contain
`{"1": Blob}`

When clicking on save, it triggers a function that is supposed to append the images to a formData(). Sadly the formData is never updated. I have the following error:

> Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'.

```js
export async function uploadImages(files, userId) {
  try {
    const images = new FormData();
    files.main && images.append("image", files.main, "main");
    files[1] && images.append("image", files[1], "1");
    files[2] && images.append("image", files[2], "2");

    const res = await ax.post(process.env.SERVER_URL + "/upload-images", {
      images,
      userId,
    });
    return "success"
  } catch (err) {
    return "error"
  }
}
```

How to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be able to see FormData object contents in console, because its not serializable. You can check request payload instead, check "Network" tab in your browser dev tools, find your request and look at the bottom of "Headers" tab to see "FormData" log. You will see something like this:
[image]

Also, you should set header "Content-Type" to "multipart/form-data" in axios.
Here is working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" multiple id="filepicker" />

    <button id="send">Send</button>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.20.0/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      const myformData = new FormData();

      document
        .querySelector('#filepicker')
        .addEventListener('change', function (event) {
          const { files } = event.target;

          Object.values(files).forEach(function (file, index) {
            myformData.append(index, file);
          });
        });

      document.querySelector('#send').addEventListener('click', function () {
        axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: 'http://google.com',
          data: myformData,
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
        })
          .then((response) => console.log(response))
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I actually log the images formData when when receiving the request in my node server. I thought I could see it through req.body.images. By doing your method, I receive the error "Error: Multipart: Boundary not found at new Multipart".

Comment: I just checked and it works. If you are using Node.js and Express, then you probably missing middleware for handling file uploads, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23843746/7546395)

Comment: But I already have bodyparser and multer to handle data parsing, do I need to install busboy as well?!

Comment: If you already have multer, then you dont need to install busboy (since multer uses busboy as a dependency). It means that there is something wrong with your code logic. You can use code snippet from the answer I linked above, or create a new question, since backend logic is not related to FormData question.

Comment: Ok I've finally found the mistake: I was trying to access the data through req.body and not req.file... It works now. However, I still need to send the user id as well in the same post request. Would you know how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried to just append another field to FormData with user id?

Comment: yes, I've added images.append("userId", userId) or ("images", userId) but the api call is never performed.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue on my react native app. To solve it I had to convert the image path to a blob. The code for my handle upload function is given below.

```
const handleUpload = async () => {
    if (selectedImage.localUri !== '') {

        const image_uri =  Platform.OS === 'ios' ? selectedImage.localUri.replace('file://', '') : selectedImage.localUri;

        const response = await fetch(image_uri);
        const blob = await response.blob();

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('image', blob, "xray_image.jpg");
  
        setLoading(true);

        axios.post("https://...", formData)
            .then((result) => {
               console.log(result);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
              
            });

    } else {
        console.log("Select a file error message");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export async function uploadImages(files, userId) {
  try {
    const images = new FormData();
    for(const file of files){
        images.append("image", file);
    }
    const res = await ax.post(process.env.SERVER_URL + "/upload-images", {
      images,
      userId,
    });
    return "success"
  } catch (err) {
    return "error"
  }
}
```

Comment: The formData is still empty.

Answer (score -2):

you have to pass the extension along with the name

```
files[1] && images.append("image", files[1], "custom-name.jpg");
```