# JQuery Ajax Form Submit with Form Data returns nothing on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

The following example below returns nothing. Could you please clarify if I missed something?

Javascript:

```js
$('#add-modal').submit(function(e) {        
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData( document.getElementById("add-modal"));
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/add-form",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (data) { console.log("SUCCESS : ", data); },
    error: function (e) {console.log("ERROR : ", e); }
  });
});
```

HTML (submission form):

```html
<form id="add-modal" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="modal-body">                    
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Classes</label>
         <select class="form-control" name="classes">
         <option value="Direct">Direct</option>
         <option value="Merketing">Merketing</option>
         <option value="Partnets">Partnets</option>
         </select>
        </div>  
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>File</label>
         <input type="file"  class="form-control" name="file">
        </div>                  
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add">
    </div>
</form>
```

Server-side (node js):

```
app.post('/add-form', function(req, res, next){
    
    console.log(req.body);
    
});
```

With my best regards,
Evgeniy

Comment: What do you mean by _"returns nothing"_? Do you mean _"logs nothing"_?

Comment: When you use ajax to send form content, the server's reply is not displayed in the browser like when you send a form the "regular" way. The only thing that'll happen is jQuery will call the function you passed as `success` and pass along the reply. So if you check your console, you should see the server's output there. Why are you using $.ajax to send the form in the first place?

Comment: @ChrisG given this looks like a modal, I imagine OP wants to submit the form via AJAX then close the modal

Comment: @Phil Probably true but not necessarily. We'll have to wait for clarification. Evgeniy?

Comment: @ChrisG, My form is shown as a modal, but... is it really important?! By "returns nothing" I mean I get empty object on my server side (added additional code) when I click on submit

Comment: I see, which express body parser did you set up and how? You're also not using the popular [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) which makes me think no body parsing at all is happening.

Comment: @ChrisG, thanks a lot. The issue is I use "bodyParser" instead of "multer". I can see my data now using "multer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form is using [express](https://expressjs.com/) to process the back-end. The form is multi-part and processing a file upload.

A multi-part processor is required to parse the form data. The comment by @ChrisG suggested using [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer). It was expected that bodyParser was doing this parsing. Replacing it with multer which needs to be imported in the express app as per the multer documentation

```
const express = require('express')
const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

app.post('/add-form', function(req, res, next){  
  console.log(req.body);   
});
```

Comment: You need to include `upload` in your route handler though; the third line on its own does nothing afaik. See here: https://github.com/expressjs/multer#usage Also, this seems to be a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691194/node-express-file-upload