# how to send data on file with sendFile in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to parse my csv file in server and return back the information after parsing and analyzing the data in csv.

I am not that used to express and i dont know any view engine.

I plan to use

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/index.html"));
```

to host my index file.

What are the other way than ajax and view template that can I send data to the index.html with sendFile.

I am sending JSON files from server to client

Any kind of help is appreciated !!!

Comment: I get lose  in this part: **once file is parsed and i need to send the data back to the index.html**.  What is your flow? #1 user enter to your home page (index.html), html loads on the web browser, then user with a button ask for something and you return the csv to populate an html table or #2 user enter to your home page (index.html) and you return the csv data in a table or something like that?

Comment: user enter the home page and there user upload a csv file and get back the desired information (which is processed in backend) and that information need to be seen in index.html

Comment: #1 Does de @Quentin answer helped you? #2 How the information(csv) is showed? #3 Are you open to use javascript with ajax to deliver a pleasant experience to your user?

Comment: yes, it seems ajax is good option. I don't need to show csv, i just need to show the processed information like count of occurrence of something in csv and it can be in table. 
Yes, i am open to use ajax as i will need to submit my file to the server anyway.

Comment: You will find a lot of information to develop an [upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691194/node-express-file-upload) feature. This question is related to the second part of your flow: How to return json as response of upload file in nodejs express?.  If you agree with that, change the title to help you. If not, continue explaining to us

Comment: Yes, my question is related to returning a response of upload file. I thought that i can parse the data that i get as an ajax response, and display it. Please correct me

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Answer (score 2):

When a client (such as a browser) makes a request you can respond with **one thing**.

You can respond with:

- The contents of a file as you are now (although you should use the `static` middleware instead of rolling your own end point handlers (without caching) one-by-one)
- A template + some data rendered into a single file (using the view engines you haven't gotten around to learning yet)
- Some JSON (typically in response to an Ajax request so the a JS program running in an HTML document get add more data to the existing HTML page)
- Something else

If sending an unmodified file is not what you want, then don't use `sendFile`.