# Saving React Blob Images in Node Not Working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, base64, blob

Here is images coming in request ( from react app)

```
req.body = {
  imageData: [ 'blob:http://localhost:3000/0bdca87f-47dc-4e56-94ae-ea24e86b6530' ]
}
```

Now I need to save this on ImageKit ( Node.Js)

```
imagekit 
    .upload ({
      file : req.body.imageData[0], // not working
     // file : 'convert_blob_to_base64' // not working either
      fileName: 'my_file_name1.jpg'
      
    })
    .then (response => {
      console.log (response);
    })
    .catch (error => {
      console.log (error);
    });
```

It does save the image but corrupted one,  I tried by converting blob to base64, then also it didn't worked out.

if I directly convert the image to base64 using `https://www.base64encode.org/` site and use that code as `file : 'base_64_directly_encoded_image'` then it works

Do I need to store the images first on Node. Js Something, Can Any one guide please.

Comment: A browser generated blob URL is just that, a URL. It contains no data and is only accessible via the browser that created it. To upload a file, you need to send it as `multipart/form-data` and handle it server-side with something like [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer). Without seeing your client-side code, this isn't really answerable

Comment: @Phil Okay let me try that too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node/Express file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691194/node-express-file-upload)