# Postman not sending binary file to express app

Tags: node.js, express, postman

I have a simple express app, however, when I try and post to it with express the body is empty.

```
app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.body);
   res.send('Hello World!');
});
```

[image]

I have a body parser setup

```
app.use(bodyParser.raw({ limit: '50mb', type: ['image/*'] }),);
```

Can I send binary files from postman?

Comment: You can try the following Postman Doc https://community.postman.com/t/how-to-upload-images-to-a-post-request/15256

Comment: You need middleware capable of handling `multipart/form-data` request bodies. Does this answer your question? [Node/Express file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50243907/283366)