# ExpressJS PUT request body data from FormData is always null

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, null, form-data

Every time I submit a PUT request to my API through a form on React, the request body always ends up being empty and I'm not entirely sure what's happening to the data.

```
const handleEdit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log("Submitted")

        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append("author", author)
        formData.append("title", title)
        formData.append("image", image)
        formData.append("body", body)
    
        // alert(author + " " + title + " " + image + " " + body)
    
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3002/api/blogs/put/${selectedId}`,{
            method: "PUT",
            body: formData,
        })
    
        if (response.status === 200) {
          alert("Updated")
          window.location.reload()
        } else {
          console.log("Error")
        }
    }
```

The code is run after the form is submitted. I've confirmed the appended data is not null and has all the correct values.

This is the request handler:

```
app.put("/api/blogs/put/:id", (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    
    const author = req.body.author;
    const title = req.body.title;
    const image = req.body.image;
    const body = req.body.body;

    console.log(req)

    db.query("UPDATE blogs SET author = ?, title = ?, image = ?, body = ? WHERE id = ?", [author, title, image, body, id], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send('Error updating blog post');
        }
        
        res.send(result);
    })
})
```

When I console.log(req) the body: {} is empty.

There is no error, the request goes through successfully and just updates all fields to null on my SQL server.

When the form is submitted, all the required fields are appended the formData, which I've confirmed are not null, and then once the request goes through, it reaches the handler and then everything is null and the body is empty.

I have also tried adding processData: false, contentType: false, to the request (individually and both).

There is no error in the console or in anything I can see.

Comment: You need middleware like Multer to handle `multipart/form-data` request bodies

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node/Express file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691194/node-express-file-upload)

Comment: Want to explain what you think `async (e) =\> { ...` does? Because the JS interpreter might have opinions about that, of the `SyntaxError` variety.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it's just an artifact of the stupid _"Ask Question Wizard"_. I'm sure OP's code doesn't actually have the `=\>`

Comment: Based on a thousand past posts, I'm not making that assumption and they can [edit] their post to include the real code =)

Comment: @Phil yup that's what was missing—many thanks.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans was not in the code, was indeed just an artifact of the Ask Question Wizard, edited to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

```
 To resolve this issue you can add enctype="multipart/form-data" and method="PUT" to your form in your React component. 
     Like this:
    
     <form onSubmit={handleEdit} encType="multipart/form-data" method="PUT">
      //your code....
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    
    I hope this will be helpful for you .
```